# Making python code faster for processing 24 million records

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to process pandas dataframe. I am applying function to one of the column.

The function is:

```
def separate_string(sentence):
    string_even = ""
    if sentence is not None:
        l = list(sentence)
        list_even = list()
        index = 0    
        for letter in l:
            if index % 2 != 0:
               if abs(ord(letter)-3) < 1114111:
                    list_even.append((chr(abs(ord(letter)-3))))
               string_even = "".join(list_even)
            index += 1
    return(str(string_even))
```

Pandas dataframe:

```
df['re'] = df.col1.apply(separate_string)
```

I am running this on PC with 64GB RAM 2.19Ghz 7 processor. Why the code never completes?

Comment: What is the shape of your dataframe? ( `print(df.shape)` )

Comment: You create `string_even` once for every loop iteration, leading to quadratic running time. Try pulling `string_even = ...` out to the same level as the return statement.

Comment: Is `sentence` a string (if it is not `None`): Then you don't need to convert it into a list. And I think you don't need the `index`-related parts: `for letter in l[1::2]:` should do it?

Comment: @firefrorefiddle changed it running the query with the change.

Comment: @Timus removed index and did slicing. Hoping for the best.

Comment: @user17242583 it's 4 by 10 million data frame

Comment: Whoa, that's gigantic.

Comment: @user17242583, yes I tried for 1/2 day data.

Comment: You tried Cython?

Comment: @user17242583 need to set it up , in the mean time I am pulling data from database again.

Comment: All python unicode codepoints -3 are less than 1114111. That test is just a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd try [Cython](https://cython.org/)izing your Python code. Essentially that would make it C code that would run (hopefully) orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want. You might have to explicitly return `None` if you need that rather than an empty string.

There are a bunch of things removed like unneeded casts and manual maintenance of an index as well as a test that codepoints are less the than 1114111 as they all are going to be.

```
def separate_string(sentence):
    return "".join(chr(abs(ord(letter) -3)) for letter in sentence[1::2])
```

We can `timeit` to see if we have improved things:

```
import timeit

setup_orig = '''
test = "This eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere in the United States and most other parts of the world at no cost and with almost no restrictions whatsoever."
def separate_string(sentence):
    string_even = ""
    if sentence is not None:
        l = list(sentence)
        list_even = list()
        index = 0    
        for letter in l:
            if index % 2 != 0:
               if abs(ord(letter)-3) < 1114111:
                    list_even.append((chr(abs(ord(letter)-3))))
               string_even = "".join(list_even)
            index += 1
    return(str(string_even))
'''

setup_new = '''
test = "This eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere in the United States and most other parts of the world at no cost and with almost no restrictions whatsoever."
def separate_string(sentence):
    return "".join(chr(abs(ord(letter) -3)) for letter in sentence[1::2])
'''

print(timeit.timeit('separate_string(test)', setup=setup_orig, number=100_000))
print(timeit.timeit('separate_string(test)', setup=setup_new, number=100_000))
```

On my laptop that gives results like:

```
5.33
0.95
```

So it seems like it might be worth exploring as part of your solution.